# using Post-quantum asymmetric ciphers instead of RSA

Tags: rsa, public-key, post-quantum-cryptography

We can't trust RSA to encrypt our Emails so what is best post-quantum cryptography system as alternative for RSA which provide good security and don't be breakable? because McEliece cryptosystem looks break with 2^60.55 bit operations..

Comment: You'll need a source for your McEliece statement. I'd expect the number of operations to depend on key sizes. If you're willing to use a large key, you should be able to reach any security level you like.

Comment: Related question: [What is the post-quantum cryptography alternative to Diffie-Hellman?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/494/what-is-the-post-quantum-cryptography-alternative-to-diffie-hellman)

Answer (score 4):

My impression is that there is no production ready post quantum scheme ATM.

NTRU seems to be decent (complete spec,  reasonable parameter-sizes and performance), but I think it's patented. No idea about the licensing terms.

But whatever scheme you choose, don't use it instead of a conventional scheme(RSA, DH, ECDH) but in addition to a conventional scheme. If you use a good construction, your protocol will be as secure as the stronger of the schemes.

Comment: Hasn't NTRU been broken several time by Faugère's work on Gröbner basis ?

Comment: @AlexandreYamajako No idea. I don't really trust any of these new schemes, that's why I recommended using it in addition to a conventional scheme.

Comment: @CodeInChaos what construction were you thinking about ? I don't think composition is a terrible idea but there are exemples in which it breaks.
Maybe pick $r$ at random then $m_0\gets r\oplus m$ and $m_1 \gets r$ ?

Comment: @AlexandreYamajako The choice of construction depends on the application requirements. But if you just need a symmetric key, you could for example choose two random keys, encrypt each one with a different scheme, and use the hash of both as your symmetric key.

Comment: Or you could avoid avoid needing to rely on "random oracle"ness of the hash, and $\hspace{1.4 in}$ just use the xor of both as your symmetric key. $\:$

Comment: NTRU is about as good as it gets right now. For certain parameters it has been broken; but picking the "wrong" IV for certain cyphers breaks them too. As NTRU receives further scrutiny it's likely to be broken again, and fixed again until it's a quality ready to replace DSA, RSA, and EC. Quantum computers are only up to 4-bits, and I estimate the 1024-bit RSA we use today is safe for another ~8 years. It doesn't hurt to plan for the inevitably though. NTRU is patented, but they've been very permissive, including openly offering cross-patent licensing (a reasonable and defensive stance).

Comment: @ChrisS did anything change the last three years?