# Is Diffie-Hellman post-quantum secure?

Tags: diffie-hellman, post-quantum-cryptography

If Alice and Bob have a secure channel for key exchange and Mallory doesn't man-in-the-middle attack them, but in the future eavesdrops on their connection and sees the key exchange, can Mallory break it like RSA with a quantum computer?

Comment: While the title (after moving _is_ at the beginning) makes a good question, the body has problems: it is assumed "a _secure_ channel for key-exchange", when I think it should be assumed "an _insecure_ channel over which it is performed Diffie-Hellman key exchange"; also "in the future eavesdrop connection and see the key exchanged" likely should be "eavesdrops the messages in a key exchange, and saves that for attack in the future". Ah and only Alice gets caps :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A quantum computer solves the discrete logarithm problem for both finite fields and elliptic curves. Being able to efficiently calculate discrete logarithms implies being able to break Diffie-Hellman, so Diffie-Hellman on either of them is not secure against an adversary who owns a large quantum computer.

There might be other groups in which DL problem is hard even against a quantum computer, but I've never heard of such a group.

Comment: what is best alternative for public use today

Comment: @mary Leave that to [your other question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/using-post-quantum-asymmetric-ciphers-instead-of-rsa), and don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: Is there a paper you know that talks about the quantum algorithm you mention in more detail?

Comment: @IonSme It's called Shor's algorithm and can break RSA/factoring, DLP, EC-DLP.