# Is pairing-based crypto post-quantum secure?

Tags: diffie-hellman, post-quantum-cryptography, pairings, quantum-cryptography

Bilinear Pairings are widely used in many new schemes like Group Signature and Aggregate Signature. The problem is whether it is post-quantum secure. In other words, does Bilinear Diffie-Hellman intractability assumption stand against a quantum computer?

With a quantum computer, [Shor's Algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9508027v2) solves Prime Factorization and Discrete Log problem in polynomial time, which nullifies the security of plain Diffie-Hellman-based schemes. But Bilinear Diffie-Hellman is a bit different since it has a mapping *e(g,g)*, instead of plain *g*. I haven't seen any quantum-resistance analysis/discussion on Pairing-related papers, nor have I seen any paper that specifically discusses this topic. Anyone has a clue?

Related pages:
[What is the post-quantum cryptography alternative to Diffie-Hellman?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/494/what-is-the-post-quantum-cryptography-alternative-to-diffie-hellman)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is pairing-based crypto post-quantum secure?

**No**. That's because solving the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) in one of the pairing's source groups breaks the pairing's security, and [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) running on a [Cryptographically Relevant Quantum Computer](https://crqc.grieu.fr) could solve such DLP.

More justification per [request](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/227239): all usages of pairings in cryptography assume that the Computational Diffie-Hellman problem is hard on one at least of the pairing's source group (often noted $\mathbb G_1$ or/and designated the Gap Group). Breaking the DLP also breaks CDH, thus a security assumption on the pairing. Typical example: Dan Boneh, Ben Lynn, Hovav Shacham, [*Short Signatures from the Weil Pairing*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00145-004-0314-9.pdf), [in JoC 2004](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00145-004-0314-9):

> Our signature scheme uses groups where the CDH problem is hard.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the reason of the statement _"...solving the Discrete Logarithm Problem in one of the pairing's base groups breaks the pairing's security"_? Which theorem or whose work proves this conclusion?

I only saw vague statements like [_"Verheul’s theorem... provides evidence that the multiplicative group of a finite field provides essentially more...security than the group of points of a supersingular elliptic curve of comparable size."_](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/456.pdf) but the reasoning is still not clear to me.